# What is the difference between Model Versioning and Data MIgration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I am new to core data, can anyone let me know the difference between Versioning and Data migration. When we do versioning and when we Data Migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioning is used just like versioning on apps to indicate different evolving variations of the same basic code except in Core Data the code evolving is the data model i.e. the entities, entity properties and relationships defined in the .xcdatamodel file.

Migration is what you perform on the end user's existing data in the persistent store in order to format/structure the store to work with the new version of the data model.

It works like this:

You release version 1.0 of your app which as a data model with a version of 1.0 as well. End user then use your app and save their data in a persistent store formatted/structure using your data model 1.0.

Then you release version 2.0 of your app and you make changes to the data model in the process e.g. you change a property name, add a property or add an entity. You would version the data model as well to something like 2.0 (the actual version names are arbitrary.) You then provide for either automatic or manual migration such that the end user data in the 1.0 persistent store file can be reformatted to the data model 2.0 format.

Answer (score 1):

Every change you make to a Core Data model results in a new version.  EVERY change.

Core Data has no concept of one model being newer than another though, it just knows they are different.  Core Data will not use a store (database on disk) created by a model version different than what you have.

That's where Migration comes in, which is simply a process to tell Core Data how to get from one model to another with the data stored in a database made by a particular model.  Core Data can try to guess (automatic migration) which for simple changes may work fine, but you can create more complex migrations by hand that carefully pluck data out of one model version and place it in a database of a newer model version.

When do you create a new model version?  After you ship an application with a Core Data model to the App Store, you should immediately create a new model version for changes so the original model version that you can create a migration path for people who have the App Store version to a later version.

When should you create a migration?  Basically any time you ship a new version to the store, you need to figure out a path from any earlier model that was in the store (and thus may be on someone's phone) to the latest data model version.  As noted, if the changes are simple you can use an automatic version, but always test (keep each app store release accessible to build from so you can test out loading an older version then migrating to a new one).

By the way, an acceptable plan is simply to delete the existing database if the model has changed at all, as long as you can put anything the user did back in the database in some way (or if the user never put anything in at all, as in a caching database).

Comment: One more thing if we delete an entity then should we manually migrate the data or any thing like that can i have a more brief example with sample model. I have lot of doubts. A new version means the same file .xcmodel and when we create a new model .xcmodelId then we need to migrate the data manually to another sqlite which will be created by the second model. make sense? or i messed up?

Comment: Deleting an entity is a simple migration. It could be done using automatic migration. Simply creating a new version and editing the model and setting it to the current version should work for you.

Comment: Sounds good. But, when the manual migration comes into picture, for what kind of changes do we use manual migaration. how can we know that we should use manual migartion?.

Comment: When you test and automatic migration fails to do what you want.

Comment: I want the data to be preserved and the new version should access the data. This is i want. neither my app should crash nor the data should be lost. Can you help me in this regard

Comment: Beyond this point you really need to get a book on Core Data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, I gone through apple docs and found that whenever we create .xcmodelID and want to migrate the data from one model to another the we can use manual migration and for version changing Automatic migration will take care of it right?

Comment: It might but it might not.  That is why you need to test, what will work on one model will not work on another.

Comment: Migration is only for end users. Don't migrate stores during development except in testing. As you are building and debugging your data model, start with a blank persistent store each build.